# C# how to check for a palindrome number

Tags: c#, palindrome

I tried to solve this problem: check if the number is a palindrome, I know that there are a lot of examples on the Internet, but I don't understand why my code isn't working.

```
using System;
class HelloWorld {
    static void Main() {
        int number = 122;
        int reverse = 0;
        while(number!=0){
            reverse = (reverse*10) + number%10;
            number/=10;
        }
        Console.Write(reverse);
        if(number==reverse){
            Console.WriteLine("The number is palindrom");
        }
        else{
            Console.WriteLine("The number isn't palindrom");
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I shouldn't use *int number = 122;* but this was my way to understand if the code is working.

Comment: _if(number == reverse)_ well, it will never be true because number is zero at this point. Using the debugger would have revealed this in no time.

Comment: What if you compare it as strings? (or is it a school assignment?)   `number.ToString() == number.Reverse().ToString()`

Comment: It reports 122 as *not* being a palindorm*e*, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your original number. In your case `number` is always `0` when comparing to the reverse number.

```cs
using System;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void Main() {
        int number = 1222111;
        int tmp_number = number;
        int reverse = 0;
        while(tmp_number!=0){
            reverse = (reverse*10) + tmp_number%10;
            tmp_number/=10;
        }
        Console.Write(reverse);
        if(number == reverse){
            Console.WriteLine(" The number is palindrom");
        }
        else{
            Console.WriteLine(" The number isn't palindrom");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within you while loop you alter the value of `number` until it's `0`. So you always end up comparing

```
if (0==reverse){
```

Answer (score 0):

The magic happens in the loop: `(reverse*10)` "shifts" your result to the next place. `number%10` is basically the remainder. With `number/=10` you go to the next place until there is nothing left.

It's useful to use the debugger in order to understand what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to convert it to a string:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int number = 1221;
        
        // convert to string, reverse it, join it, parse it to an int
        int reversed = int.Parse( string.Join("", number.ToString().Reverse()));
        
        if(number == reversed)
            Console.WriteLine("The number is palindrom");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("The number isn't palindrom");
    }
}
```

You don't need to parse it back to an int, but your example uses integers.

Comment: you are right, but OP was asking "why my code isn't working".
However, the string approach is way cleaner, especially for bigger numbers... :)

Comment: Just for curiosity because it doesn't matter at all here, but a very quick test over 100000 iterations of the code above and an adjusted code using integer ops shows a really important difference in performance. Probably the creation of the array and its conversion back to a reversed string take its toll here

Comment: @Steve It is cheaper, if you want strings, to just write a loop, so go: `static bool IsPalindrome(string str) { for (var i = 0; i < str.Length / 2; ++i) { if (str[i] != str[str.Length - 1 - i]) { return false; } } return true; }` This method works for strings in general. Then you can do `IsPalindrome(number.ToString())` for the special case of an `int`.

Comment: @Steve Yep, requesting memory etc is much more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather an approach I have followed from general pseudocodes available for multiple programming languages for implementing a palindrome program

```
class Solution{
public static void Main(string[] args){
   int number = 123;
   if(IsPalindrome(number))
      Console.WriteLine(number+" is a palindrome number");
   else
       Console.WriteLine(number+" is not a palindrome number");
  }
static bool IsPalindrome(int m){
    //convert parameter to string
    string inp = m.ToString();
    //reverse using a loop
    string rev="";
    for(int i=inp.Length-1;i>-1;i--){
        rev += inp[i];
    }
    //check and return 
    if(rev==inp){return true;}else{return false;}
  
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `temp*temp*temp`, a cube?

Comment: Yeah my answer checks for a palindrome in a three length number

Comment: So for example, if at some point in the loop, `num` ends in a figure `7`, then `temp` becomes `7`, and then `temp*temp*temp` is `7*7*7` which is `343`. So 343 is added to `total`. How is it useful? Your code has typos as well, like `=/` instead of `/=`.

Comment: Hey corrected the typos, give an example of a palindrome number whose initial or counter division gives a remainder of seven

Comment: `IsPalindrome(727)`

Comment: Give me some time to debug this and I really appreciate it mods are moderating answers

Comment: is it working on your end now?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Palindrome
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Palindrome: Is a word, phrase, or sequence that reads 
    ///             the same backward as forward
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="number"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool CheckPalindrome(int number)
    {
        int forward = number;
        int reverse = 0;
        while(forward != 0)
        {
            reverse = (reverse * 10) + forward % 10;
            forward /= 10;
        }
        return (reverse == number);
    }
}
```